# 404 NOT FOUND Manager Tomcat 8.5.57

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos, http-status-code-404

[image]

I just installed tomcat on Centos 7 and it's working fine until I want to go to `/manager/html` or `host-manager/html`.

I get a message that says: `The required resource is not available. [/manager/html]`

Comment: Did you place the authorization in the users config file as well as in the context config file? This walkthrough is pretty usable: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: i did, the tomcat-users.xml and context it's ok. I think it may be a directory problem but I don't know how to verify it

Comment: connect to the tomcat machine with ssh; cd into the tomcat directory (usually it is in /opt/tomcat); use the ls command to list the owner of the file (ls -lla); check if the "." directory is owned by the user with which tomcat is running. your ls -lla should look like this:
drwxrwxr-x 10 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul  6 20:06 .
marking, that the tomcat directory is owned by tomcat user and group (assuming tomcat is the user for the tomcat ;) ) as well as rwx on it for tomcat and r-x for everyone else

Comment: It's like this: 
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root   tomcat   220 ago  3 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root      20 jul 30 12:03 ..

Comment: what are the webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/ do look like inside the tomcat directory? If they look the same as the tomcat itself, this may be your issue. you can see the values with the same ls from above. It should say drwxrwxr-x tomcat tomcat. Also check the other folders inside tomcat dir if they are readable via the group. so the second r-x must be set on every folder.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 9 root   tomcat   220 ago  3 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root      20 jul 30 12:03 ..

Comment: do I have to change them? they all have to be owned by tomcat?

Comment: I think so. Try to follow Step 4 from the tutorial above.

Comment: I did and nothing changed, when I installed the tomcat I also did that step.

Comment: could you please post the complete ls -lla where you stand within the tomcat directory?